# Python CLI argprse for methods

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

I have problem with create argparse for methods:
My main.py

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument( "--word", "-w", help="Find score for word", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()

second = SecondOption()
print(args.word)
second.score_from_word(args.word)
```

class SecondOption:

```
class SecondOption():
    def score_from_word(word):
        SCRABBLES_SCORES = [(1, "E A O I N R T L S U"), (2, "D G"), (3, "B C M P"),
                (4, "F H V W Y"), (5, "K"), (8, "J X"), (10, "Q Z")]
        LETTER_SCORES = {letter: score for score, letters in SCRABBLES_SCORES
             for letter in letters.split()}
        score = 0
        for w in range(word):
            if w in LETTER_SCORES.keys():
                score += LETTER_SCORES.get(w)
        print(score)
```

After writing in console: python main.py -w KOT I want to get scores (7 for this example), but I get TypeError: takes 1 argument but 2 were given. How can I fix that?

Comment: What's the purpose of `SecondOption`? `score_from_word` could (and should, until proven otherwise) be a simple function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `SecondOption` class has a bound method in it named `score_from_words` with an incorrect signature... or at least not as your expecting.

Since the method is bound to the class.  The first arg sent will be an instance of `self`, always for bound methods (methods in a class).  So in reality this call is the looking for signature `self_from_word(self, word)` hence the two args sent when you only specified one.

The fix is to add `self` as the first param to the bound method.

```
class SecondOption():
    def score_from_word(self, word):
        pass
```

Comment: Or, as I noted in a comment to the other answer, the method might be turned into a function outside the class, as the class isn't needed from the code shown.

Comment: Ok, it works fine now!! But i have another question: Let's say, that I want to create another method in the same class, but this method will return the highest score from the file. I have this code which works, but how to add another argparse for another method? Lets say -w works for word wrote in console. And now I want to write -f to get score from file

Comment: @Frendom: Please ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

When using function/method inside class, first argument should always be self.
So you need to change from `def score_from_word(word):` to `def score_from_word(self, word):`. Also I found another mistake in your code: `for w in range(word):` should be `for w in word:`, since you're not trying to get position of the letter, but the letter itself.

Comment: Also, as shown here  `score_from_word` could be a function (outside the class), instead of a method that is part of the class; if that approach is taken, then there'd be no need to pass `self`. (Also note that `self` is a convention; any legit variable name could be used.